# display dynamic content based on url slug on custom page

Tags: permalinks, urls, routing

i have a custom page named locations and i want the url to load like this:

```
/locations/california
/locations/nevada
etc..
```

and upon each page load of the given url as above content is loaded based on it. So for example if California is loaded specific information to california would be loaded. How would I go about doing this in wordpress? I tried visiting /locations/california and i get a 404 so i guess word-press is looking for the permalink /locations/california

Comment: Where is your logic to display a location information? Is it in the page template or are pulling the information through Javascript? My hunch, without knowing more, is that you want to use a custom-post type of locations. You would set the post-type slug to 'locations' and then create a new Location post for each location. If you really do need `/locations/*` to all go to the same page, you then basically need to add a new rewrite rule that matches `^locations/(.+)`, then rewrite it to the page with the slug of `location`.

Comment: its a custom page template. The url should actually look like domain.com/state/ and it doesnt have to be on the same page. i just dont know anyother way of doing it.

Comment: actually, i think that if i jsut create each state as a page and list all the cities/pages on there it would alaso work. im an idiot lol. should've seen this.

Comment: Try creating a page with slug /locations/. Then create each state as a page whose parent is /locations/. The url for page nevada will appears /locations/nevada